# Child component doesn't update correctly with state update in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Simply i have a list item, that contain a list of names, clicking any list item change the color of that item, this is my logic:

```
const App = () => {

    const items = [
        {
            name: 'peter',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'Mark',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'john',
            id: 3
        }
    ]

    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    const [names, setNames] = useState(items)

    const setClickedItemId = (id) => {
        setId(id)
    }

    const turnItemRed = () => {
        setNames(prev =>  prev.map(i => i.id === id ? {...i, color: 'red' } : i))

    }


    return (
        <div className="app">
            <ul className="items">
                {
                    names.map(i => {
                        return (
                            <Item 
                               item={i}
                                setClickedItemId={setClickedItemId}
                                turnItemRed={turnItemRed}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

function Item({item, ...props}) {
    const { name, id} = item;
    const { setClickedItemId, turnItemRed } = props;
    return (
        <li
            className={`${item.color === 'red' ? 'red' : ''}`}
            onClick={() => {
                setClickedItemId(id);
                turnItemRed()

            }}
        >{name}</li>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This renders a list of items, i need two clicks to have an item turning into red, which means the child component doesn't catch the most recent version of state, **but**:

Just adding that line of code before the return statement in parent components,

```
const showingItems = names.map(i => i.id === id ? {...i, color: 'red'} : i)
```

and then using that variable `showingItems` to render the list instead of state variable `names` make it right **and don't know why**

So, why the child components `Items` doesn't get the most recent version of the state while storing the state in a variable makes it work??

Comment: In `turnItemRed` you pass `prev => ...` to `setNames` you don't have `prev` defined anywhere, plus you're passing a function to `setNames` which will change it from what it was previously (`items`) to now `names` being equal to that function. You can change that line to `setNames(names.map(i => i.id === id ? {...i, color: 'red' } : i))` and it should work properly.

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but this didn't fix the problem, i think prev is equal to using names here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are batched and your onClick triggers 2 functions which does state updates. The second function doesn't receive updated value due to the async behaviour.

Just pass the id to `turnItemRed` function instead of grabbing it from state.

**App**

```js
    const turnItemRed = (id) => { //<----take the id
        setNames(prev =>  prev.map(i => i.id === id ? {...i, color: 'red' } : i))

    }
```

**Item**

```js
function Item({item, ...props}) {
    const { name, id} = item;
    const { setClickedItemId, turnItemRed } = props;
    return (
        <li
            className={`${item.color === 'red' ? 'red' : ''}`}
            onClick={() => {
                setClickedItemId(id);
                turnItemRed(id) //<---- pass the id

            }}
        >{name}</li>
    )
}
```

**Edit**
A quick demo of the above issue and the fix is [here in the demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/child-component-arg-prev-value-issue-fix-qklxw?file=/src/App.js) . Just adding this so it might help other readers in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
export default  () => {

    const items = [
        {
            name: 'peter',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'Mark',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'john',
            id: 3
        }
    ]

    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    const [names, setNames] = useState(items)

    const setClickedItemId = (id) => {
        setId(id);
        turnItemRed(id);
    }

    const turnItemRed = (id) => {
        setNames(prev => prev.map(i => i.id === id ? { ...i, color: 'red' } : i))
    }
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <ul className="items">
                {
                    names.map(i => {
                        return (
                            <Item
                                item={i}
                                setClickedItemId={setClickedItemId}
                                turnItemRed={turnItemRed}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

function Item({ item, ...props }) {
    const { name, id } = item;
    const { setClickedItemId, turnItemRed } = props;
    return (
        <li
            style={{ color: item.color === 'red' ? 'red' : ''}}
            onClick={() => {
                setClickedItemId(id);
            }}
        >{name}</li>
    )
}
```

Comment: when the value is set to the state, we can't get the state change value on the next line.

in react class, there is an  option to get it on the next line using the state's callback function
thi.setState(value_to_set,callback_function)